# Ion motion in uniform axial magnetic field and radial electric field

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I'm trying to model an ion's 3D motion in a constant/uniform axial magnetic field and a radial electric field (similar to a cylindrical magnetron, but two positive parallel center electrodes offset by some distance and a negative cylindrical shell).

The inputs are the voltages applied to the center electrodes, the axial magnetic field strength, the ion mass and charge, the spacing between electrodes and their length.

The first block is the electric field expression (The input is the voltage applied to the electrodes.)

```
Clear[x, y, z];

e0 = 625000 /(22468879468420441 Pi); (*Farad/meter*)
e = 1.60217662*^-19 ; (*coulombs*)
m = 3.343583719*^-27; (*Kg*)

cylinRadius = 0.00125;(*meter*)
shellRadius = cylinOffset + ( 2 cylinRadius);(*meter*)
cylinLength = 2 shellRadius; (*meter*)

coaxCharge = 
 cylinVoltage (2 Pi e0 cylinLength) / 
   Log[shellRadius/cylinRadius]; (*Coulomb*)

PhiLineSegment[x_, y_, 
  z_] = (coaxCharge/(4 Pi e0 cylinLength)) Log[(
    cylinLength/2 + z + 
     Sqrt[(x + cylinOffset)^2 + y^2 + (z + cylinLength/2)^2])/(-(
      cylinLength/2) + z + 
     Sqrt[(x + cylinOffset)^2 + 
      y^2 + (z - cylinLength/2)^2])] + (coaxCharge/(
    4 Pi e0 cylinLength)) Log[(
    cylinLength/2 + z + 
     Sqrt[(x - cylinOffset)^2 + y^2 + (z + cylinLength/2)^2])/(-(
      cylinLength/2) + z + 
     Sqrt[(x - cylinOffset)^2 + y^2 + (z - cylinLength/2)^2])];
ELineSegment[x_, y_, z_] = Grad[PhiLineSegment[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];
```

The magnetic field is constant and uniform

```
BField[x_,y_,z_] = {0,0,0.15};(*Tesla*)
```

NDSolve (**not working - having trouble with the derivative of the BField**)

```
cylinOffset = 0.05;  (*meter*)
cylinVoltage = 1;

steps = 2;
stepSize = 0.01;
angpos = Pi;

nds = NDSolve[Join[Thread[{x''[t], y''[t], z''[t]} ==
 { -e/m (ELineSegment[x[t], y[t], z[t]][[1]] + 
    BField[x[t], y[t], z[t]][[3]] y'[t] - 
    BField[x[t], y[t], z[t]][[2]] z'[t]),
  -e/m (ELineSegment[x[t], y[t], z[t]][[2]] + 
    BField[x[t], y[t], z[t]][[1]] z'[t] - 
    BField[x[t], y[t], z[t]][[3]] x'[t]),
  -e/m (ELineSegment[x[t], y[t], z[t]][[3]] + 
    BField[x[t], y[t], z[t]][[2]] x'[t] - 
    BField[x[t], y[t], z[t]][[1]] y'[t])}],
    Thread[{x[0], y[0], z[0]} == {cylinRadius Cos[angpos], 
       cylinRadius Sin[angpos] + cylinOffset, 0}], 
    Thread[{x'[0], y'[0], z'[0]} == {0, 0, 0}]], {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 
    steps}];

data = Table[
   Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. nds], {t, 0, steps, stepSize}];

ListPointPlot3D[Flatten[data, 1], PlotRange -> All]]
```

System Layout

[image: System Layout]

Lorentz Force Equations for reference:
[image: Lorentz Force Equations]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will NDSolve help you?

Comment: @Wjx I'm using NDSolve, but I need help modifying the equations to add units/quantities for the inputs desired ... right now I have paths based on arbitrary units and values.

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem, so please provide the expressions for E and B.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I updated the question to include these expressions.

Comment: It appears that `LineSegment` is a potential, not an electric field. To explain what the question has to do with *Mathematica*, you should state how you're invoking `NDSolve`.

Comment: @Jens I edited the question to include how I'm using NDSolve

Comment: In addition to the errors I pointed out in the answer, you aren't using the electric and magnetic field vectors correctly. To get the components of a vector like `B`, you say `B[x[t],y[t],z[t]][[1]]`, etc. You should look at the *Mathematica* documentation center and look for tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *Summary*

We give the solution of the problem by first calculating the potential, setting up the equation of motion and solving it numerically assuming some typical inital conditions. The results are shown as plots of the time dependence of the components of the position vector and as a 3D-plot and an animation of the ion trajectory.

This code gives a framework for experiments with respect to changing the initial conditions and also of other parameters.

Because of the complexity of the physical system many more interesting evaluations can be made, including those which the author of the OP had or has in mind.

### *Potential and electric field*

Wihtout changing the overall picture we simplify the writing by setting parameters equal to unity if appropriate and abbreviating

```
{a <- segLength/2, d <- segOffset};
```

Let us first calculate the electric potential which we assume attractive to the ion (this was done before by Jens in his answer).

The potential of the electrode at x = d is calculated first.

In order to reduce the execution time we take the indefinite integral

```
h = -Integrate[1/Sqrt[(x - d)^2 + y^2 + (z - z1)^2], z1];
```

and then insert the border values to get

```
hd = (h /. z1 -> a) - (h /. z1 -> -a) 

(*
 Out[267]= Log[-a + z + Sqrt[d^2 - 2 d x + x^2 + y^2 + (-a + z)^2]] - 
 Log[a + z + Sqrt[d^2 - 2 d x + x^2 + y^2 + (a + z)^2]]
*)
```

Taking into account the contribution of the electrode at `x = - d` the total potential is given by

```
\[Phi] = hd + (hd /. d -> -d)

(*
Out[268]= Log[-a + z + Sqrt[d^2 - 2 d x + x^2 + y^2 + (-a + z)^2]] + 
 Log[-a + z + Sqrt[d^2 + 2 d x + x^2 + y^2 + (-a + z)^2]] - 
 Log[a + z + Sqrt[d^2 - 2 d x + x^2 + y^2 + (a + z)^2]] - 
 Log[a + z + Sqrt[d^2 + 2 d x + x^2 + y^2 + (a + z)^2]]
*)
```

The potential can be visualized in several ways using for example `ContourPlot` and `ContourPlot3D`.

Here we deal only the electric field vector,
specifying also the geometry of the electrodes

```
\[Phi]1 = \[Phi] /. {a -> 1, d -> 1};

e = -D[\[Phi]1, #] & /@ {x, y, z} // Simplify;
```

This 3D_Plot Shows the electric field vector in the space around the electrodes

```
VectorPlot3D[e, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 PlotLabel -> "The electric field vector", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

### *The motion of the ion*

We define the position vector

```
vr[t_] = {x[t], y[t], z[t]};
```

and the velocity vector of the ion, respectively

```
vv[t_] = D[vr[t], t];
```

The magnetic induction is

```
vB = {0, 0, B};
```

Hence the Lorentz force becomes

```
fL = Cross[vv[t], vB]

(*
Out[289]= {B Derivative[1][y][t], -B Derivative[1][x][t], 0}
*)
```

From now of we set `B = 1` for simplicity.

The equation of motion is then

```
eq = Thread[
    D[vr[t], {t, 2}] - fL == ( e /. {x -> x[t], y -> y[t], z -> z[t]})] /. 
   B -> 1;
```

We put the initial conditions of the motion of the ion in a list `init`, and can then study various situations by varying `init`.

The following lines are easy to understand so I don't supply any explanation.

Illustrative example:
Ion starts in the origin with velocity in the x-z-plane

```
init = {x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, z[0] == 0, 
   z'[0] == 1/2};
eq1 = Join[eq, init];
tt = 10^2;
sol = NDSolve[eq1, vr[t], {t, 0, tt}];
rr[t_] = vr[t] /. sol[[1]];
Plot[rr[t][[1]], {t, 0, tt}, PlotLabel -> "x(t)"]
Plot[rr[t][[2]], {t, 0, tt}, PlotLabel -> "y(t)"]
Plot[rr[t][[3]], {t, 0, tt}, PlotLabel -> "z(t)"]
ParametricPlot3D[rr[t], {t, 0, tt}, PlotLabel -> "Trajectory of ion", 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

An animation shows the development of the chaotic character of the trajectory (dynamic updating must be enabled):

```
Animate[ParametricPlot3D[rr[t], {t, 0, u}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Trajectory of ion", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}], {u, 0, 50}]
```

Comment: I updated your diagram and added it to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my post by removing the draft picture and asking another question concerning the field configuration.

Comment: The electric field potential should go to zero at the shell (V=0). This may be able to be ignored.

Comment: I'm getting lots of errors saying the system is under determined ... is it possible that your answer is missing a line of code?

Comment: I have found the typo and have corrected the code (xx->vr). Please try again.

Comment: So I have your code running and have symbolic motion, but I'm still struggling with adding units so that the movement is accurate for a given system dimensions/voltage/BField

Comment: (1) What are you really after? What are the Initial conditions you wish to investigate? (2) The condition of vanishing potential on the shell would complicate the problem of finding the potential essentially.

Comment: I've figured it out based on your help ... Thanks. I can award the bounty after 24 hours have passed.

Comment: Your welcome. Modeling the shell seems to be more important than I originally thought. I may post a question on physics stackexchange for guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Your code cannot work because you defined the potential and electric field with incorrect syntax. Here is a corrected version:

```
Clear[x, y, z];

PhiLineSegment[x_, y_, z_] = (segCharge/(4 Pi e0 segLength)) Log[(segLength/2 + z + 
        Sqrt[(x + segOffset)^2 + 
          y^2 + (z + segLength/2)^2])/(-(segLength/2) + z + 
        Sqrt[(x + segOffset)^2 + 
          y^2 + (z - 
             segLength/
              2)^2])] + (segCharge/(4 Pi e0 segLength)) Log[(segLength/2 + z + 
        Sqrt[(x - segOffset)^2 + 
          y^2 + (z + segLength/2)^2])/(-(segLength/2) + z + 
        Sqrt[(x - segOffset)^2 + y^2 + (z - segLength/2)^2])];


ELineSegment[x_, y_, z_] = Grad[PhiLineSegment[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];
```

I removed the `x[t]` and other time-dependent functions from these definitions, because you should use the same names in the body of the function that also appears in the argument pattern on the left, i.e., `x` etc.

Of course you also have to set numerical values for the remaining variables , e.g., `segOffset` and `segVoltage`. These functions will then be called in `NDSolve`, presumably in the parts that were omitted (just written as `blah, blah` which makes it impossible to say anything else in this answer).